# メールアカウントについて教えてください

Tags: dns, mail, google-workspace

#### 質問内容

GoogleWorkspaceでアカウントを管理している場合、お名前ドットコムで同一の独自ドメインを使ったメールアドレスを作成することは可能なのでしょうか？

(例)
GoogleWorkspaceでsample@example.com を作成し、お名前ドットコムでsample2@example.com を作成することは可能でしょうか？
※なお設定は下記の通りとします。

##### 設定

独自ドメイン：お名前ドットコム
メールアドレス：GoogleWorkspace
ネームサーバ：お名前ドットコム
メールサーバ：Google
SPF設定：Microsoft,google

以上、ご存知の方ご教授いただけますと大変助かります。ご確認の程よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問文が意味不明です。DNSというのはメールアドレスを作るもんではありません

Comment: はい。それは知っています。アカウントの作成方法がGWS以外の他のサービスでも作成可能か知りたく。

Comment: お名前ドットコムでメールアドレスを作るというのは、[お名前メール](https://www.onamae.com/service/mail/)のサービスでメールアドレスを作って、メールの送受信をしたいと言うことですか？

Comment: はい！そうゆう意味です☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お名前ドットコムのサービスに特別な制限がなければメールアドレスを作ることは可能です。ただし当然そのままでは"sample2@example.com"にはメールは届きません。

このような状況は

- 例えばオンプレからGWSへの移行期間中
- GWSに移行できないアドレス変更不可能なメールボックスの救済

などで必要とされますので、GWSでは｢メールのルーティング」機能が提供されています。GWS以外でもビジネス向けに提供されているメールサービスであれば同等の機能があるはずです。

詳細は[GWSのマニュアル](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650?hl=ja)を参照してください。

一点触れられていない注意事項として、"sample2@example.com"からGWS以外を用いてメールを送信する場合には、適切なSPFなどのメール認証の設定が必要です。

--

[raccyさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/98438/5793)で指摘があったとおり、sample2@example.comがお名前ドットコムのサーバを使用して自ドメインあてのメールを送信しようとすると問題が発生します。

このような送信が必要な場合、

- GWS にもsample2@example.comを作成し送信にはGWSを使用する(アカウントがあったとしても、sample2@example.com宛てのメールはルーティングの設定が優先されます)
- またはGWSでもお名前ドットコムでもない別のサービスを使用する

ことで対応できます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ふむふむ。そうすると、お名前ドットコムで作成したメールアドレスを使えるようにするには、SPFでお名前ドットコムの設定が必要ということで合ってますでしょか？(GWSでルーティング設定する前提)

Answer (score 1):

Google Workspaceとお名前メールのそれぞれで同じドメイン、別々のアカウントを作り、それぞれのサービスでメールの送受信がしたいと言うことであれば、サービスを十全に満たすことは、**たぶん無理**です。なぜなら、下記のことが実現不可能だと思われるからです。

- お名前メールを使って、お名前メールのアドレス「sample2@example.com」からGoogle Workspaceの「sample@example.com」へメールを送る。

上記のようにメールを送っても、お名前メールには「sample@example.com」が存在しないため、ユーザーアンノウンで弾かれると推測されます。通常、メールサーバーは自分が管理しているドメイン宛のメールは管理しているデータベースからユーザーを検索して、受信箱に入れます。もし、ユーザーがいなかった場合は、ユーザーアンノウンで返す(または拒否する)という処理をします。この処理はメールサーバー自体がそのドメインを管理するかどうかの設定で決まるため、MXレコードは関係ありません。

MTAサーバーソフトウェア(Postfix、Sendmail、MS Exchange等のこと)のコンフィグを直接編集が可能であったり、Google WorkspaceやMicrosoft 365のようにメール配送経路に関して細かい設定が可能であれば、存在しないユーザーは別のサーバーに送るとか、ユーザー毎にサーバーを変えるとか、エイリアスを使うとか、そういった方法で上記の動作を回避できる場合があります。しかし、お名前メールのサービスのヘルプなどを見る限り、そのような細かい設定は出来るようになっていないと思われます。

事前に、お名前メールでそういった細かい設定が可能であるか、サポートに確認しておくことをお勧めします。

Answer (score 0):

メールアドレスを構成する文字列のうち、`@` より前がユーザー名、`@` より後ろがドメイン名になります。

「Google Workspaceでアカウントを管理している」のであれば、ユーザーを追加するのは当然 Google Workspace で行う必要があります。